# How to check for uniqueness in the derived field of model in Django

Tags: django

I have a model like

```
class InfoFromFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_from_file = models.DateField()
    file = models.FileField()
    file_hash = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

with a corresponding admin class

```
class InfoFromFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Information source', {'fields': ['File']}),
    ]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # custom action here to extract info from file
        # before creating and saving the model
```

I have a separate function for creating a hash of the file.

So, the only input field in the form is the file upload. I want to prevent duplicate files to be uploaded at all, that is, before saving the model as a part of form/model validation. If the model is attempted saved and the hash already exists, an IntegrityError is thrown.

I know about the Model.validate_unique() method, but I don't know how to apply it in the ModelAdmin.save_model(*) method.

To summarize, my question is:
**How can I validate for uniqueness in a different field than the one provided by the model form?**
Should I make use of javascript to create the hash of the file before the admin-user hits the save button? Or make use of any other hidden fields?

**EDIT:** A future expansion to the site would be to allow users to upload such files (or do the same processing resulting in an output pdf-file, possibly without saving the user's file), albeit not needed now.

Comment: Saving a model from the admin triggers the `full_clean` method, so you would simply create a validation step for your scenario. Just add a validation check for the uniqueness of your field, if it's not, raise a `ValidationError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a custom form. You can validate whatever you want in `clean_<field>` method of your form. It should be similar to this:

```
class InfoFromFileForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_File(self):
        file_obj = self.cleaned_data['File']
        hash = get_hash() # whatever you use to get file hash
        if InfoFromFile.objects.filter(file_hash=hash).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_("The hash must be unique.")
        return file_obj
```

Then in your admin class

```
class InfoFromFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # your things
    form = InfoFromFileForm
    # more things
```

Comment: This is a possible approach, but it requires a bit more of code, the other possible solution is to override the clean method in the model directly, and make the checks within it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: It depends on whether you want to add validation globally or just for admin interface, i.e., user input. If the goal is protection from bad user input, form.clean_<field> seems like a better idea. If the goal is to handle this case for both admin input and object creation from code, model.clean is prefferable.

Comment: Totally agree with you :) just mentioned that as additional information :) although to my looks, this kind of checks could possibly lead to DOS attacks (multiple zero byte file requests)

Comment: So, if I want to add validation globally, while avoiding attacks, which approach is the better? Custom form or model.clean()? (As I understand your answer now, @KarolisRyselis, the custom form is better and safer for global validation. It's there a reason why?

Comment: And it worked like a charm! Both approaches, that is. Thank you both!

Comment: @pyborg the form approach is ok if you want to validate this particular form. The validation will work when user clicks submit in your form. If you want to run validation from somewhere else in your code, you cannot do this with form approach. If you use model.clean, you can call `obj.full_clean()` on your object and it will raise the error if hash is not ok. It is up to you - if you want to control user input and nothing more, use form.clean_File, if you think you need to verify your data outside of the form and model.full_clean looks useful to you and you're going to use it, model.clean then